# How to bind events in angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to angular and having problem to bind an click event to my directive.

I have an `ul-list` with a links in each li. When I click a link I want to do a service call that adds or removes the clicked items ID and refresh the list.

When refreshed, each list items will show if an id is "marked" or not.

Can anyone help me?

html view:

```
<a href="#" class="showbooklist" qtip="12568">
    <img src="image.png">
</a>
```

Directive:

```
listControllers.directive('qtip', ['boklistorservice', function (boklistorservice) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',                
        controller: ["$scope", "$attrs","$element", "boklistorservice", function ($scope, $attrs,$element, boklistorservice) {                              
            boklistorservice.getdata().then(function (data) { //serice call to gett data
                $scope.booklist = data;
                $element.qtip({ //use the jquery.tip2.js tooltip plugin
                    content: {
                        text: getcurrentbooklist($attrs.qtip, data.barnenskrypin.booklistor)
                    },
                    position: {
                        my: 'bottom center',
                        at: 'top center'
                    },
                    hide: {
                        fixed: true,
                        delay: 300
                    }
                });
            })           
        }]
    };
}]);

//function returns a string. An ul to show in the toolbox 
var getcurrentbooklist = function (bookid, arr) {
    var rettext = "<ul>";
    $.each(arr, function (item, val) {
        item;
        var inlist = false;
        $.each(val.bookitems, function (i, v) {
            if (v.bookid == bookid) {
                inlist = true;
                return false;
            } else {
                inlist = false;
            }
        });
        if (inlist) {
            rettext += "<li><a (NEED A CLICK EVENT HERE and pass bookid) > " + val.booklistnamn + "-- MARK </a></li>";
        } else {
            rettext += "<li><a (NEED A CLICK EVENT HERE and pass bookid) >" + val.booklistnamn + "--</a></li>";
        }
    });
    rettext += "</ul>";
    return rettext;
};
```

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick

Comment: element.bind('click', clickingCallbackFunction);

Answer (score 0):

Use the link function of a directive (code untested):

```
listControllers.directive('qtip', ['boklistorservice', function (boklistorservice) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A', 
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function () {
                //Do your work here
            });
        },             
        controller: ["$scope", "$attrs","$element", "boklistorservice", function ($scope, $attrs,$element, boklistorservice) {                              
            boklistorservice.getdata().then(function (data) { //serice call to gett data
                $scope.booklist = data;
                $element.qtip({ //use the jquery.tip2.js tooltip plugin
                    content: {
                        text: getcurrentbooklist($attrs.qtip, data.barnenskrypin.booklistor)
                    },
                    position: {
                        my: 'bottom center',
                        at: 'top center'
                    },
                    hide: {
                        fixed: true,
                        delay: 300
                    }
                });
            })           
        }]
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

jquery.tip2 adds the html to body so you need to find the content in body and add the click event

```
$element.qtip();
angular.element(document.body).find('[qtip container id or class or element] a').bind('click', function () {
    //Do your work here
});
```

Comment: hi when searching for angular.element(document.body).find('[qtip container id or class or element] a'). the jqueryobject is empty. console just show: Jquery()  i can find the container but nothing inside the container.(content: { text: getcurrentbooklist...} qtip.content that function getcurrentbooklist provide.) do i have to compile the string in some way to access it.